# Using 'fminunc', I receive Optimization completed because the size of the gradient is less than the value of the optimality tolerance

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, nonlinear-optimization

I use `fminunc` to find the value of `B` (2x4 matrix) that minimzes the difference between the corresponding elements in two vectors as indicated in the attached code. In other words, I want to find the  `B` that makes the elements of  `beta_d` (1x4 vector) which is a function of `B`  matrix, equal to the corresponding ones of a "given" `beta_u` (1x4 vector), i.e.  `beta_d(1,1) = beta_u(1,1) && beta_d(1,2) = beta_u(1,2) && beta_d(1,3) = beta_u(1,3) && beta_d(1,4) = beta_u(1,4)`. 
However, I usually receive the following message without getting any result and the program seems to go on an infinite loop!

```
Local minimum found.
Optimization completed because the size of the gradient is less than
the value of the optimality tolerance.
<stopping criteria details>
```

The code is as follows:

```
% System paramters:
N = 2;
K = 4;
C_l = 4;
H = [-0.3208  -0.9784; -1.5994   -1.4689; -1.5197   -0.4568; -0.0993   -0.7667]; % 4*2 matrix
A = [-1 1; 0 1]; % 2x2 matrix
C = [-0.20  0.4  0.6 -0.2; -0.2  0.4  0.6 -0.2; 0.4  0.2 -0.2  0.4; 0.4  0.2 -0.2  0.4]; % 4x4 matrix
P = [250000   0   0   0; 0  250000  0   0; 0   0  250000  0; 0  0  0  250000]; % 4x4 matrix
beta_u = [50.2207   50.2207   20.3433   20.3433]; % 1x4 vector
beta_d = zeros(1,4); % intial value
B = zeros(2,4); % intial value
% store inputs to a struct for shorter syntax
s = struct();
[s.H,s.A,s.C,s.P,s.C_l,s.N,s.K] = deal(H,A,C,P,C_l,N,K);
%fminunc optimization
while (sum(abs(beta_u-beta_d))>=0.1)
    initial_guess = randn(2,4);
    OLS = @(B_d,input_vars)sum((beta_u-myfun(B_d,input_vars)).^2); % ordinary least squares cost function
    opts = optimoptions(@fminunc,'MaxIterations',10000,'MaxFunctionEvaluations',50000,'CheckGradients',true);
    B = fminunc(OLS, initial_guess, opts,s);
    input_vars = s;
    [beta_d, D_d] = myfun(B,input_vars);      
end

% calculate beta_d from B and the other inputs
function [beta_d, D_d] = myfun(B,input_vars)
    % load parameters
    s = input_vars;[H,A,C,P,C_l,N,K]=deal(s.H,s.A,s.C,s.P,s.C_l,s.N,s.K);
    for j = 1:1:N
        d(j) = (B(j,:)*P*B(j,:)')/((2^(2*C_l))-(norm(A(:,j))^2));
    end
    D_d = diag(d);
    for i = 1:1:K   
        V_d(i) = C(i,:)*P*B'*H(i,:)'*inv(1+H(i,:)*(A'*D_d*A+B*P*B')*H(i,:)');
        sigma_d(i) = norm((V_d(i)*H(i,:)*B-C(i,:))*(P^(1/2)))^2+(V_d(i)^2)*(1+H(i,:)*A'*D_d*A*H(i,:)');
        beta_d(i) = ((P(i,i))/sigma_d(:,i));   
    end
end
```

Comment: The infinite loop is written by you. You have a while condition, that seems to never be true. You see that `fminunc` has a maxiterations? that is to avoid an infinite loop. You need to do the same in your while function. Now, the second answer is why `fminunc` is not returning an answer. It would be that your math problem is not properly solvable, or you have a bug, but we can't really help with that.

Comment: But, when I change the values of the given system parameters, the fminunc sometimes gives me a result matched with the while function! .. I think this means that the math problem is solvable

Comment: No.... The values are part of the math problem. "x/c=b" has a solution for most values of `c` and `d`, but if `c=0` it has no solution. Your equation is defined by its values. If problems did not depend on their numerical value, I would not have a PhD :D

Comment: But, If I remove the while loop in the code indicated in the question, the result of the fminunc is not the desired one as I receive beta_d vector not equal that in beta_u. So, How can I obtain beta_d = beta_u without entering in an infinite loop?

Comment: Refer to my first comment, it is the answer.

Comment: But, if I set a maxiteration for the while function, it will give me an undesired result, where beta_d will not equal beta_u.

Comment: And if you don't, if ever beta_d is not equal to beta_u, it will go forever. Up to you.

Comment: So, is there any other way to obtain beta_d = beta_u?

Comment: We seem to be going in circles here, and unfortunately I don't have the time for this. All the information I can give is in the first comment. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I really appreciate your help. I'll return back to your first comment and try to figure out the problem.